# apache how to limit per user ip

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, .htpasswd, connlimit

i have a password protected directory with hundreds of users in htpasswd file.

i want to allow download of files on these conditions:

1. check if username is valid (already done).
2. check if another connection with the same username exists. (the are modules to check connection from same ip exists but i have not found any based on username)
3. if 2 is correct check if both connections come from the same IP.

#### in other words how to limit each user to download from only 1 ip simultaneously?

i've seen hundreds of articles and questions about how to limit number of Connections based on IP. but none based on `User`. to clarify by a `User` i am referring to a `valid-user` in `htpasswd` file.

an example :  lets say i have a htpasswd with the following users:

```
simon:$apr1$oL5flt.H$ayy6GOm0TblhH3lJXqf9o0
john:$apr1$JLGdTKlz$72ImnSlauIsCRV4lkrqE3/
```

and i've added `require valid-user` to htaccess.

- `john` connects to get file.zip from `192.168.2.8` with 1 connection. (allow)
- `john` makes another 31 connections to a total of 32 (or any number really) from `192.168.2.8`.(allow)[because ip matches already active connections]
- `john` connects from `192.168.2.9` to get any file before closing previus connections .(deny)[because active connections have different ip]
- `simon` connects from `192.168.2.8` (same ip as active connections) , (allow)[no other connections from simon]
- `john` from `192.168.2.8` finishes downloading `file.zip`
- `john` from `192.168.2.9` wants to download a file (allow).

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use iptables?  This below may not be perfect but I hope it points you in the right direction.  If you have multiple virtual hosts, where you don't want this restriction, you may have to place it on a separate IP or play with the destination a bit.

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 1 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

Comment: how is this related to question ? i specifically noted in question i don't want to `limit connection based on ip` rather based on `username` in htpasswd file , there is like 50 questions about what you said in Server Fault , please read the question again...

Comment: also in question i noted that each user should be able to get over 32 connections from the same ip , your solution does not allows that yet it allows same user to download from multiple ip's , so kind of opposite of what i asked for ... although i thank you for your time to post an answer but unfortunately it was not really helpful :(